# Joining user to groups based on template user strange behaviour

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm writing a script in PowerShell that creates users. This script adds the user to groups based on a template user with the department name. When used in my script like so:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {name -eq "Temp$($Department.LookupValue)"} -Properties memberof |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty memberof |
    Add-ADGroupMember -Members $sAMAccountName
```

this unfortunately doesn't work, nor does it give any errors.

However, when I run just the line of code it works just fine

```
Get-ADUser -Filter {name -eq "TempICT"} -Properties memberof |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty memberof |
    Add-ADGroupMember -Members usern
```

Comment: Try `| foreach {add-adgroupmember ...}` instead of plain piping to `add-adgroupmember`. As I understand it, you just receive more than a single group identity, and you need to add `$samaccountname` to all of em.

Comment: @Vesper You should add your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, you can cycle through the group names with `foreach-object` using `Add-ADGroupMember`, but this is going to result in a call to AD for every group the user needs to be added to.  It may be more efficient to use the `Add-ADPrincipalGroupMemebership` cmdlet, which will add the user to multiple groups in a single operation:

```
$Groups = Get-ADUser -Filter {name -eq "TempICT"} -Properties memberof |
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty memberof 
Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $sAMAccountname -MemberOf $Groups
```

Answer (score 0):

The following line of code does work, I guess the problem was with the filter not being able to process the dot notation. `Get-ADUser "Temp$departmentsn" -Properties memberof | Select-Object -ExpandProperty memberof | Add-ADGroupMember -Members $gebruiker`

It's not 100% how I wanted it since I now search for the netbiosname instead of the name property but it works. Because of the 20 character limitation for netbiosnames I had to make a substring to make it work for all my departments.